# Echo something every 24th iteration

Tags: php

I have just stumbled across an issue. I have been trying to make sure that whenever the id reaches a number based on 24 (24, 48, 72, etc) it would echo a certain output. Does anyone have any clue on how to do this?

Best wishes,

```html
$mysql_connection = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM data") or die(mysql_error());
         
while($bar_data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($mysql_connection)) { ?>
    
<div class="item-wrapper">
 <div class="item">
  <div class="brand">
   <p class="brand-content"><?php echo $bar_data["brand"]; ?></p>
  </div>
  <div class="type">
   <p class="type-content"><?php echo $bar_data["type"]; ?></p>
  </div>
  <div class="data">
   <p class="data-content"><?php echo $bar_data["content"]; ?>, <?php echo $bar_data["color"]; ?></p>
  </div>
  <div class="price">
   <p class="price-content"><?php echo $bar_data["price"]; ?></p>
  </div>
  <div class="img">
   <?php
    $generator = new \Picqer\Barcode\BarcodeGeneratorPNG();
    echo '<img src="data:image/png;base64,' . base64_encode($generator->getBarcode($bar_data["barcode"], $generator::TYPE_CODE_128)) . '">';
   ?>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
<?php
 // When $bar_data["id"] reaches 24 based echo the following:
  echo '</div><div class="page">';
 }
}
?>
```

Comment: What have you tried? Looking at the code, I don't see anywhere that you're checking the id if it's a factor of 24

Comment: Look up http://php.net/manual/en/internals2.opcodes.mod.php. If the number you're on `mod 24 == 0`...

Comment: `if ($bar_data['id'] % 24 === 0) ... `

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use modulo arithmetic: http://php.net/manual/en/internals2.opcodes.mod.php

```
if ($bar_data['id'] % 24 == 0)
{

}
```

If the number you are on within your loop `mod 24 == 0` then you can display the appropriate content.

The above code means that the number in `$bar_data['id']` has no remainder when divided by 24. Values such as 24, 48, 72 satisfy this condition.